# How to change the clearSearch icon with bootstrap-table?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a table with the search clear button enabled,
but I would like to change the [icon](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/6e2cb16836069cbb26a7f2e84b522e29ebe9cdf4/src/constants/index.js#L76) from `fa-trash` to `fa-undo`.
I tried below but that doesn't work.

```
<table id="table"
   data-icons="{ clearSearch: 'fa-undo' }"
   data-search="true"
   data-show-search-clear-button="true">
```

Is there an way to only change the `clearSearch` icon being used via the [data-icons](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#icons) attribute? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overridden the `clearSearch` globally using:

```
  $.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults.icons, {
    clearSearch: 'fa-undo'
  });
```